# Android GridView setSelection

Tags: android, gridview, selection, selected

When a Fragment is inflated, by default I want to item no 10 to be selected.
I tried it with `gridview.setSelection(10);` but it is not working for me. I read in the forum that others have done it successfully , but I am not achieving the correct output. what should I do?

```
orari_fine = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView4);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, orari_f);
orari_fine.setAdapter(adapter1);
orari_fine.setSelection(10);
orari_fine.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
         OraFine = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();

    }
});
```

XML

```
<GridView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/selector"
    android:id="@+id/gridView4"
    android:background="#9051585B"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:numColumns="8"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView13" />
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `gridview.setSelection(10);` try using `gridview.setItemChecked(10, true);`

Answer (score 0):

try do this

```
   // set item postion you wanna select
    orari_fine.setSelection(10);  
    orari_fine.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);  
    orari_fine.requestFocus();
// Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed
    adapter1.notifydatasetchanged();
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?